# How to add comma to foreach loop

Tags: php, magento, loops, foreach

In Magento single product view page I am using foreach loop to display the name(s) of a category of the current product with `echo()` function

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?>
    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but when a product is assigned to multiple categories the result is **Category Name Category Name Category Name** which is not formatted properly. Is there any way to add comma (Example: **Category Name, Category Name, Category Name**)  after each category except the last one may be by using implode() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. No implode. Just check if you already printed the first category. If so then add a comma before each other category.

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php $firstSet = false;?>
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?>
    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?>
    <?php if ($firstSet):?>, <?php endif;?><a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
    <?php $firstSet = true;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Is there any way to remove space between Category name and Comma(,)? For example **Category Name , Category name** to **Category Name, Category name**

Comment: @KevinS. Yes. See my update. Just moved the if statement on the same row as the `a` element.

Comment: I did tried that but for some reason it is not working. May be something to do within the Magento. Here is my final code `<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?><?php $firstSet = false;?><?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?><?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?><?php if ($firstSet):?>, <?php endif;?><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>')" type="button"><span><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></span></a><?php $firstSet = true;?><?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: @KevinS then, are you sure there is a space? Maybe it's just some margin or padding of the `a` element.

Comment: I did tried disabling all the styles of `a` element but it still show it up as `<a href="urltocategory">Category Name  </a> 
        , `

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Since you are getting category name please try this:

```
<?php echo $_category->getName().", "; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?>
<?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName()."," ?> 

</a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>

Note :  concatenate , using .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
   foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id){
      $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id);
      $category_str  = '<a href="' . $_category->getUrl() . '">' . $_category->getName() . '</a>, ';
   } 
?>

<?php echo trim($category_str, ', ') ?>
```